# How to count Distinct value and date less than in the same line

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to calculate the titles & subtitles that over 60 days old. I tried this query but it didnt work.

`count(distinct [Tracking ID1] case when [Date]   < DATEADD(DAY, -60, '1/5/2021')`

[image]

```
select 
    [Line of Business],
    count([Tracking ID]) as [Total # Subtitles],
    count(distinct [Tracking ID1]) as [Total # Titles], 
    count(case when [Date]   < DATEADD(DAY, -60, '1/5/2021') then 1 else 0 end) as [# Subtitles No Action Yet over 60 days], 
    count(distinct [Tracking ID1] case when [Date]   < DATEADD(DAY, -60, '1/5/2021') as [# Titles No Action Yet over 60 days]
    
from table
where 
[Status] like '%active%'
group by [Line of Business]
order by [Line of Business]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use count instead of sum :

```
select 
    [Line of Business],
    count([Tracking ID]) as [Total # Subtitles],
    count(distinct [Tracking ID1]) as [Total # Titles], 
    COUNT(case when [Date] < DATEADD(DAY, -60, '1/5/2021') then 1 else NULL end) as [# Subtitles No Action Yet over 60 days], 
    COUNT(distinct CASE when [Date] < DATEADD(DAY, -60, '1/5/2021') THEN [Tracking ID1] ELSE NULL END) AS [# Titles No Action Yet over 60 days]    
from table
where 
[Status] like '%active%'
group by [Line of Business]
order by [Line of Business]
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't get me closer to my goal. I still need help with this line of code. 
    count(distinct [Tracking ID1] case when [Date]   < DATEADD(DAY, -60, '1/5/2021') as [# Titles No Action Yet over 60 days]

Comment: You have an extra "("  here: COUNT((

Comment: What an odd solution. Normally one would write `COUNT (DISTINCT CASE when [Date] < DATEADD(DAY, -60, '1/5/2021') THEN [Tracking ID1] END)`